# How to view conversion data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I have inherited a sitecore project. In this project there are goals already setup. I can see this via the Marketing Center > Goals.

**My questions is** how to view the conversion data for each of the goals?

This is what I tried: selected the 'Analyze Tab', Clicked 'Reports button' on the ribbon, then under 'Item Reports' selected 'Pages - Goals and Events'.

Doing the above generates a report but the values are `0`, we are expecting it to show values.

Sitecore and DMS version: 6.5

Comment: You'll need to include the Sitecore version and the version of OMS/DMS that you're using.

Comment: thanks divamatrix, I have updated the sitecore and dms version

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might have already found the answer to your question, but here goes the answer.

Few things to make sure that have Engagement Value Points being specified in the Goals that already exists.
For example

- Newsletter Registration - 25 Engagement Value Points
- Online Pricing Quote - 50 Engagement Value Points
- Request for Demo - 100 Engagement Value Points

Also Relevance is set. ***Relevance = Value/Visits***

Refer [Sitecore Executive Dashboard Cookbook 6.5](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/executive_dashboard_cookbook_sc65-a4.pdf) Section 1.2

If the above is in place and works fine please check the assoication of the Goal with the content item is correct. Refer [Sitecore Marketing Operations Cookbook 6.5](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc65-a4.pdf) Section 3.1.3

Let me know if the above works or helps.